# Google Xml parser

Tags: xcode

can anyone help me in getting the formatted date from the parsed XML.
I can format that using NSXML formatter but now i am found difficulty in using it through Google XMl parser. where i can get the values through the key but i need that in a formatted way,

```
return [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
 [[[xmlItem elementsForName:@"title"] objectAtIndex:0] stringValue], @"title",
[[[xmlItem elementsForName:@"link"] objectAtIndex:0] stringValue], @"link",
    [[[xmlItem elementsForName:@"pubDate"] objectAtIndex:0] stringValue], @"Date",
                      nil];
```

here the pubDate is returned as such from xml with hr,min,sec i need the date alone.

Thanks in advance!!!!

Comment: I think you should edit your question to be relevant.  "Google Xml Parser" is meaningless and so is any reference to XML, when what you want to know is how to perform date/string conversions.

Comment: Thank u trojanfoe.My question is that does GDataXMLNode(google parser) has any date formatter similar to NSXML Date formatter?

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer

```
//cell.textLabel.text = [item objectForKey:@"pubDate"];

NSString *yourXMLDate = [item objectForKey:@"pubDate"];
NSDateFormatter *inputFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[inputFormatter setDateFormat:@"E, d LLL yyyy HH:mm:ss Z"];
NSDate *inputDate = [inputFormatter dateFromString:yourXMLDate];
NSDateFormatter *outputFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[outputFormatter setDateFormat:@"MMM dd, HH:mm a"];
NSString *outputDate = [outputFormatter stringFromDate:inputDate];

cell.textLabel.text=outputDate;
```

where this results in Oct 12, 12:30 AM. whatever parser used in the xcode this works fine....